# Using numpy.where to prevent out of bound

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, where-clause

I am trying to look up values in an array based on an array of indices. This array of indices can contain indices that could be out of bound. In that case I want to return a particular value (here 0).

(I could use a for loop but that would be too slow.)

So I am doing this:

```
data = np.arange(1000).reshape(10, 10, 10)
i = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
i[0, 0] = 10
condition = (i[:, 0] < 10) & (i[:, 1] < 10) & (i[:, 2] < 10)
values = np.where(condition, data[i[:, 0], i[:, 1], i[:, 2]], 0)
```

However I still get an out of bound error:

```
IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10
```

I guess it is because the second parameters is not lazily evaluated and is evaluated before the function call.

Is there a solution in numpy to access an array based on a condition but still retain the order? By retaining the order I mean that I can't filter the array first because I could loose the order in the end result. In the end, in that particular example, I still want the values array to contain a 0 when the indices are out of bound. So the end result would be:

```
array([ 0, 345, 678])
```

Comment: Can't you just do `i[i >= 10] = 0` and get rid of `condition` and `where`?

Comment: The code crashes when evaluating `data[i[:, 0], i[:, 1], i[:, 2]]` because you did not use your `condition` in any way to get rid of `i>=10`.

Comment: @roganjosh There is not guarantee that data[0][0][0] is 0

Comment: @LukeSkywalker I didn't suggest that anything was guaranteed. All my code does it look for _any_ elements that are greater than or equal to 10 and sets them at 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every column of the indexing array stores the indices for each dimension. We could generate the mask of valid ones (by the bounds) and set the invalid ones in it as zeros. i.e. out of bounds cases would be indexed by `[0,0,0]`, then let the array be indexed by this modified version and finally use the mask again to reset the invalid ones, like so -

```
shp = data.shape
valid_mask = (i < shp).all(1)
i[~valid_mask] = 0
out = np.where(valid_mask,data[tuple(i.T)],0)
```

A modified compact version of the same without changing `i`, would be -

```
out = np.where(valid_mask,data[tuple(np.where(valid_mask,i.T,0))],0)
```

Answer (score 1):

First index, then apply a fix to correct values.

```
shp = np.array(data.shape)
j = i % shp 
res = data[j.T.tolist()]
res[(i >= shp).nonzero()[0]] = 0
```

```
print(res)
array([  0, 345, 678])
```

Comment: Huh, I guess I've misinterpreted this question badly

Comment: @roganjosh I understood the question as "I want numpy to not index data when the index is invalid, but the arguments to `np.where` are evaluated before `where` is actually run, so how do I do this?"

Comment: I assumed the output should have been 3x3 but index 10 was replaced by the value at index 0. As it stands, I think it could go either way until OP clarifies.

Comment: In the end I am trying to the values inside the data array based on the indices.